# Linux DNS server change

Tags: linux

We are having linux system in our organisation having 700 systems . I need to change the DNS server of every other system. I cant go and change the DNS in each and every system so i need a script, so that all the respective users can run the script and change the DNS config of their system

Comment: Why aren't you using DHCP to assign the DNS server?

Comment: Why aren't you using puppet to control your systems' configuration?

Answer (score 2):

Write a script to change [`/etc/resolv.conf`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/resolv.conf), or if you have DHCP, push the changes from DHCP.